# Mobile Publisher Playground App Login Error on LWR site

Tags: login-errors, lwr, mobile-publisher, frontdoor.jsp

I an building a LWR experience site (using the 'build your own' template), and have a custom login page.  This works perfectly well in a browser, but on mobile publisher it displays an error in console and redirects back to the login page.

The LWC component calls an apex class passing username and password.  The apex class does a site.login using code below.  startUrl is a blank value :

**ApexPages.PageReference lgn = Site.login(
trueUsername,
password,
startUrl
);**

it returns **lgn.getUrl()** back to the LWC component.

the component checks that a url has been returned and uses the following to send the user to the url provided by the login:

**window.open(this.loginURL, '_self');**

This works perfectly well in a chrome browser.

The error being produced when tryign the login through mobile publisher is as follows :
when the login page first loads these errors are in the console :

- *Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 401 (Unauthorized)
  /orgpoc/s/webruntime/api/services/data/v56.0/connect/communities/0DB250000004IC3GAM/managed-content/delivery?language=en-US&asGuest=true*
- *Error in handler Session Timeout. OAuth Plugin is not available.*

When logging in, the following error is shown in the console :

- *Routing error: (LWR4008) A preNavigate hook listener blocked routing to "/orgpoc/secur/frontdoor.jsp"*

There's no issue with the actual login call, the username and password are fine, and it works fine within chrome browser.  When I log in via mobile publisher it simply fails to send the user to the secur/frontdoor page properly to log them in presentign the error above in the console log.  I viewed this by using usb debugging and chrome://inspect to see the output.

Any help on this would be much appreciated.

Comment: did you ever figure out a solution for this? I am having same problem in LWR site.